# Windows RPC call fails with error 87 (0x57) ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rpc, c++builder-11-alexandria

I'm upgrading a huge suite of programs from C++ Builder 6 and MSVC 6 to C++ Builder 11 and Visual Studio 2022.

The suite of programs use C++ Builder for the UI and MSVC for non-visual utilities and services. The C++ Builder UI communicates with the services using RPC. MSVC generates rpc client and server stubs using the MIDL compiler. C++ Builder 6 happily accepts and compiles the .c and .h client side stubs.

I've converted the MSVC projects to V2022 and I've set the Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp). I'm doing the MSVC conversion first as it's much easier, Very few code changes were needed - mainly removing throw() specifications and using unique_ptr, etc.

The MIDL compiler produces slightly different stubs to MSVC V6 - now it produces separate .C files for the server and client stubs, whereas the V6 put them both in one .C file. C++ Builder 6 is happy to compile the new .C client side stubs.

However, the C++ Builder V6 programs receive error code 87 (0x57) whenever it tries to call any RPC function using the NdrClientCall2(...) functions in the client stubs... The target service is running. I set up Visual Studio to debug the service (by attaching to the process) and set a breakpoint to the function that should respond to the call - the breakpoint is never hit, which I think means the RPC call is not getting that far.

If I replace the service with the one compiled with MSVC 6, everything works as expected.

I'm not sure how to proceed - I'm wondering if there is some incompatibility between the new MSVC 2022 code and the old C++ Builder V6 code, but they both are targeting the same Windows version... And I don't have any experience in debugging RPC itself. Sadly, the codebase is huge, so I can't post a simple example.

I'm just looking for any pointers about how to figure out what the problem is...

Andy

Comment: *Very few code changes were needed - mainly removing throw() specifications and using unique_ptr, etc.* -- Maybe the code changes are more involved than you expected.  Getting new code to compile is one thing -- ensuring the functionality is the same is another.

Comment: Maybe you should show the code that doesn't work

Comment: Paul, you were right. The in the code there were calls to RpcSsAllocate(...) without a preceding call to RpcSsEnableAllocate() and there were throwing an exceptions. These calls were not inside the stub code and, if I am reading MS's documentation right I need to call RpcSsEnableAllocate() first.

MSVC 6's compiler produced code that didn't need this and I'm not 100% certain why - RPC coding is a new area for me.

I have, in MSVC 2022 had to supply my own midl_user_allocate(...) and midl_user_free(...) functions, and I wonder if this is the difference?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is structured such that the calls to RpcSsAllocate are not neatly followed by calls to RpcSsFree, but the debugger confirms that midl_user_free is called once for each call to RpcSsAllocate , with the same pointer that RpcSsAllocate returns.

I have therefore coded midl_user_free(...) to call RpcSsFree followed by RpcSsDisableAllocate().

It's working in my test environment, but I'm not at all confident about the calls to RpcSsDisableAllocate() - does it free up the calls to RpcSsEnableAllocate() one at a time or all at once?